# Python BASE_DIR is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to run a module called `local_settings-example.py` which i got from [here](https://github.com/lukerosiak/pysec).

The module is on the `C:\Python27\pysec-master` file and it is given below

```
import os

from settings import PROJECT_ROOT

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':  'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME' : os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db_name.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'sdfgtardyure34654356435'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver; added in v1.4
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'

############### PYSEC specific variables

# assumes this directory exists
DATA_DIR = "%s/pysec/data/" % PROJECT_ROOT
```

However it keeps giving me weird *bugs*. Whenever i try to run it, it gives me this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 4, in <module>
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db_name.sqlite3')
NameError: name 'BASE_DIR' is not defined
```

How can i work this problem around? And most important can the `BASE_DIR` be given in another module in the same `file(C:\Python27\pysec-master)`?

Comment: The file you claim to have copied doesn't include any reference to a BASE_DIR. You've somehow mixed up some of your own local settings file into the one from that project, but managed to delete the bit that defines BASE_DIR.

Comment: If i put the directory where the module is in a `String` format the module does not give me any bug. I thing this is right. I hope

Comment: Hey @ExoticBirdsMerchant in this case, you don't really need BASE_DIR, Since your project is using PROJECT_ROOT. They represent the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a variable called `BASE_DIR`. Simple- otherwise Python doesn't know what it is and you get that error. I don't know what it should be, so I'll leave you to put that in.

To access that variable from another module, you would need to `import` that file:

```
import relevant_file
```

Then you would access it like this:

```
relevant_fle.BASEDIR
```

Comment: I am glad you broke the 5k mark! I think it something that has to do with modules directory... i am not sure though

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant Lol it's not 5k, just 4.5k. Anyway, perhaps `BASE-DIR` is in `settings.py` as well? Try extending your `import` to `from settings import BASE_DIR, PROJECT_ROOT`.

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant Glad I could help. If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it in about 2 minutes? You can do it my clicling the tick below the vote counts so it is green. Thank you.

Comment: Nop it must be somewhere else the `BASE_DIR` but i got the idee